# phrasing a php string using a predefined template

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to phrase php strings and "explode" it into 3 variables based on a template.

I tried doing it using the `explode` function, however it's a little messy.

```
    list($name, $role) = explode(' (', $value);
    list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(' ', $name);
```

For example, I have these strings:

```
$str_1 = "Jane Joe (Team 1)";
$str_2 = "John Joe (Bank)";
```

I need to extract `first_name`, `last_name` and the `role`, which is the string in the parentheses.

I also tried regular expressions, but I'm a little rusty with regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Regular Expression to get that parts of input string:

PHP preg_match function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
preg_match('~^(.+) (.+)\((.+\))$~', $str_1, $matches);
```

That kind of call makes that the @matches array contain:

- $matches[0] : whole input string
- $matches[1] : first name
- $matches[2] : last name
- $matches[3] : role

You also can check if that pattern match input string:

```
if(preg_match('^(.+) (.+)\((.+\))$', $str_1, $matches)) {
    // do something with matches here
}
```

Comment: `preg_match('~^(.+) (.+) \((.+)\)$~', $str_1, $matches);` slight correction

Comment: Could you tell me, what does that ~ make to the pattern? I'm really curious about that as I have not used that kind of patterns before.

Comment: it's just a random character to limit your regular expression. a slash is often used instead of ~, but i like ~ more. when using preg_match you have to enclose your pattern with an arbitrary character to separate it from modifiers, which follow. example: '~^(.+) (.+) \((.+)\)$~D' uses the modifier D to have $ not include newlines.

Comment: thanks, i ended up using your regex expression. your solution also covers strings with special symbols. however, it adds up a closing parentheses to the role. @Basti solution fixes that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$str_1 = "Jane Joe (Team 1)";  
preg_match("/^(\w*)\s?(\w*)\s?\\((.*)\\)$/", $str_1, $matches);  
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: looks interesting, however my zend studio editor is complaining about "bad escaped sequence /w"

Comment: Note that with this regex the first and last names are optional. The string '(role)' will still work and will give empty values for the first and last names. So it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex for this (you may have to play with the first two grouping's allowable characters, below allows word characters and hyphens):

```
$str_1 = "Jane Joe (Team 1)";
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/([\w-]+) ([\w-]+) \((.*)\)/', $str_1, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1]; // Jane
    echo $matches[2]; // Joe
    echo $matches[3]; // Team 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `explode` and `substr`:

```
list($first_name, $last_name, $role) = explode(" ", "Jane Joe (Team 1)", 3);
$role = substr($role, 1,-1);

var_dump($first_name, $last_name, $role);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/Ike0M

Of course this assumes 1 word first and last names.

Comment: +1 for a novel approach, though I would tend to think that 'one-word first and last names' is probably not a safe assumption.

Comment: yeah, it works, but I rather avoid using the explode function for that. If there's a parentheses in the name, the code won't work

Comment: @Phoenix None of the solutions listed handle anything besides one word first and last names.

Comment: @aporat None of the other solutions support a parentheses in the name either.

Comment: @AlecGorge That's a good point.  I think one would have a little more ease adapting a regex solution to multi-word first/last names than an `explode()`-based one, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: No, it isn't easier. How would you know if it is a 2 word first name or a word last name? A plain string is not a good way to handle a full name at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would argue that a different approach would be cleaner than passing in a pure string of data, a regular expression would probably achieve this for you.

```
$strArray = array(
    "Jane Joe (Team 1)",
    "John Joe (Bank)"
);

foreach($strArray as $str) {
    $match = array();
    preg_match("/^\(w*)/", $str, $match);
    $firstName = $match[0];

    preg_match("/\s\(w*)/", $str, $match);
    $lastName = $match[0];

    preg_match("/\((\w)\)/", $str, $match);
    $role = $match[0];
}
```

Comment: u don't need to initialize $match before calling preg_match and you can find all three parts of the string with just one pattern. the separator for array values is `,` not `;`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, @Basti. You don't *have* to indent your code, but it helps readability. That's why I initialised the array. Also, I split `preg_match` into separate lines because regular expressions are difficult enough to understand, especially for beginners.